# Platform definition file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I'm working on adding a third-party drive to the kernel that we're working on but I'm having a hard time getting a part of it, I'd like some help.

Following the drive's guide, I stopped at this point:

**(1) Below is the definition to be added to the platform definition file.**

In my case I'm using bcm2709, I deduced that the platform definition file is arm/mach-bcm2709/bcm2709.c, **is it correct? (1)**

**(2) pn5xx_i2c.h must be included in the platform definition file**

I deduced that I needed to add

```
#include <linux/pn5xx_i2c.h>
```

Since I added pn5xx_i2c.h in *linux/includes*, **is that correct? (2)**

**(3) Then the declared nfc_board_info structure must be added to the platform using dedicated procedure (platform specific).**

This I no longer know what to do (3)

Thanks

Comment: What version of the Linux kernel?

Comment: @PeterL. 4.4 (kernel_rpi) any help would be appreciated

Comment: Forget about platform code, use device tree. For the three questions you asked, the answer is **no**,

Comment: @Jonny When the device tree was introduced to the kernel, projects moved away from the platform model.  If you want to see how platform code worked, look back at the 2.6.x kernel trees.

Comment: @0andriy I figure out that the answer is yes, stay tuned before responding with no basis however as you and PeterL. have suggested, the best way (and recommended) is for device tree, thanks for making my life easier.

Comment: @PeterL. thank's for your time

Comment: hi, i have the same problem as you. how did you solve #3?